# Rails Template Error with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I deploy to heroku, when I try to create a  new comment, which is nested in blueprints, I throw and error. I have tried so much that I can't even remember it all to write it in here. Let me know if I am missing something obvious. Thanks!

```
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CommentsController#new as HTML
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"blueprint_id"=>"1"}
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/blueprints/1/comments/new host=aeh.herokuapp.com fwd=68.200.131.243 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=3ms service=44ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:29:in `block in _app_views_comments__form_html_erb___740426380689644965_39997500'
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `category' for #<Comment:0x00000005109730>):
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     30:     </div>
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered comments/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.4ms)
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (3.1ms)
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:     <div class="controls">
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:     <%= f.label :category, :class => 'control-label' %>
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/comments/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_comments_new_html_erb___765962496684666744_33764340'
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:   <div class="control-group">
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments__form_html_erb___740426380689644965_39997500'
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     32: 
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     29:       <%= f.text_field :category, :class => 'text_field' %>
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     31:   </div>
2012-12-18T00:07:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:35:in `new'
2012-12-18T00:07:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-12-18T00:07:27+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-12-18 00:07:27] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2012-12-18T00:07:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2012-12-18T00:07:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec     rails server -p 46647`
```

_form partial below

```
<%= form_for [@blueprint, @comment], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
 <div class="control-group">
<%= f.label :comment, :class => 'control-label' %>
<div class="controls">
  <%= f.text_area :comment, :class => 'text_area' %>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="control-group">
 <%= f.label :blueprint_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
   <%= f.number_field :blueprint_id, :class => 'number_field' %>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="control-group">
 <%= f.label :user_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
  <%= f.number_field :user_id, :class => 'number_field' %> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="control-group">
<%= f.label :project_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
<div class="controls">
   <%= f.number_field :project_id, :class => 'number_field' %>
 </div>
  </div>
 <div class="control-group">
 <%= f.label :category, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
   <%= f.text_field :category, :class => 'text_field' %>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-actions">
   <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
              blueprint_comments_path(@blueprint), :class => 'btn' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Lets see the code for the action, the view *(specifically, where the partial is rendered)*, and the partial. The error is saying you're calling `.category` on an instance of `Comment` within your `_form.html.erb` partial, and that `.category` doesn't exist as a method/attribute on your model.

Comment: I should add that everything works fine when I am running it locally. This only happens on heroku.

Comment: Does the Comment belong to the Categori

Comment: Did you miss some files in your last commit/push?

Comment: And, how can I check if I missed files in my last push?

Comment: The comment table has a column category:string

Comment: That column exists in production? I'm going to bet **no**.

Comment: I even tried to run a migration on heroku to add the column, after db:migrate it still isnt working.

Comment: Show us the migration where this column is added. Have you actually **verified** in the heroku database that the column exists in the table?

Comment: Deefour, when I looked at my console it showed that you are right. How come my migration didnt work? How should I go about adding the column if it didnt work with

     heroku run rails g migration AddCategoryToComments category:string

Comment: Fixed by adding migration to local end and pushing to heroku again. But now I throw an error when db:migration saying I already have the column.

Thanks deefour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Fixed by adding migration to local end and pushing to heroku again. "