# Heroku error caused by form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, heroku

I'm having the same issue as this persons question: [Rails Template Error with Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924432/rails-template-error-with-heroku)

regarding action template errors caused by a rails forms only when deployed to heroku. Everything works locally. This question has been answered however I do not understand the answer. It says "Fixed by adding migration to local end then deploy to heroku". What does it mean by add migration to local end and how do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: If you have any migrations added then you need to run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: You should start by checking what is the error cause in the Heroku logs.

Comment: Yep, already checked the logs thats how I knew I had the same error. Anyhow, I had some migration files that were stoping me from running heroku run rake db:migrate. After I got rid of them I was able to run the command it worked fine.Thanks Paven!